# Receiving the 404 error in getting of static django files

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

Please help to understand what I do wrong.

I have in my settings.py :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\','')+'/'
```

And in index.html :

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/css/table.css" %}">
```

But I still have the error 404 :

```
"GET /var/cardsite/cardsite/static/css/table.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1696
```

I have this file :

```
ls -la /var/cardsite/cardsite/static/css/table.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 77 Sep 25 16:15 /var/cardsite/cardsite/static/css/table.css
```

So what is going on?

P.S. My project stored on "/var/cardsite" and I want to make static folder on each application, like in example is default application "cardsite"

thanks

Comment: have you run the command `collectstatic`, before using the static files?

Comment: yes, but it didn't help

Comment: I've added an answer, check if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [Django_Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)
You must also have a `STATIC_ROOT` option set before you can use the static files, heres some help
add this to your code:

```
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\','')+'/'

# Here you can add all the directories from where you want to use your js, css etc
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  # This can be same as the static url
  os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),

  # also any other dir you wanna use
  "/any/other/static/path/you/wanna/use",
]

# This is the static root dir from where django uses the files from.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static_root")
```

you will also need to specify it in the `urls.py` file, just add the following code to the `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

after you add this, run the command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will copy all the statics you need to the static root dir.